# Is it normal for `adb` not to work consistently with a usb extension cord?

Tags: android, usb

Is it reasonable that a modern high end smartphone would not function with a 1.5 meter usb extension cord or should I consider the cable to be faulty and return it? From a glance it seems to work, but things like `adb push` will never ever finish (left it running for 15 minutes or so). Mind you, I am aware that a powered USB cable would definitely fix my problem, I am just trying to determine whether getting another USB extension cord should fix my problem, or whether this is normal expected behaviour.

Comment: I am quite aware that this isn't a typical SO question, but I do believe it's fully on topic under tools developers typically use. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is not implausible. Connectors tend to create impedance discontinuities and having them in the middle of a cable (vs only near the ends) can make for ugly signal reflections. It is also possible that your cable is constructed with the wrong wire geometry and thus impedance.  An interesting experiment would be to see if you could force it to operate at USB full speed (vs the faster high speed), perhaps by configuring the host's driver.  You could also try things like another extension, or a keyboard/mouse on the extension vs something more likely to be USB high speed, like a modern webcam.

Comment: @ChrisStratton So the conclusion of that is that it's reasonable that `adb` or a modern webcam would not work with a usb extension cable?

Comment: What's the combined length of the cables?  From what I've seen and tried, anything under 10 ft works, anything over gets wonky.  Have you tried connecting without the extension to see if you still have the issue?

Comment: @freshsmoe USB to micro usb is like 15 cm, cable itself is 1.5m, so that's a lot less than the 10ft you mention. And without the extension cord it works perfectly of course.

Comment: @DavidMulder  This sounds like the cable might be faulty. Is this a USB 2.0 port that you are connecting to as well?  I can't find anything online, but potentially USB 1.0 ports might have a shorter allowed length.  It looks like the max length for USB 2.0 is 5 meters for high speed devices, 3 meters for low speed.  Either way, it sounds like you are far short of both.  I found the additional details here:
http://www.yourcablestore.com/USB-Cable-Length-Limitations-And-How-To-Break-Them_ep_42-1.html

Comment: @freshsmoe Nope, it's a usb 2.0 port (or a usb 3.0 port... I am supposed to have two of those, but not sure which two I internally wired them to anymore :P ). Either way, seems that this isn't that normal. The cable isn't an expensive one or anything, but it seems this shouldn't happen even with a super cheap one.

Comment: Signal integrity is as much or more of an issue than length, and depends a lot on the relative geometry of the two wires forming the D+/D- pair, which gets disrupted wherever you have a connector.   This is going to be *more* of an issue at USB High Speed than it is at the slower USB Full Speed.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Someday I really should take a couple of courses in electronics and more low level stuff :( . Either way, from a high level perspective it doesn't seem possible to force USB Full Speed on Windows, so I guess I will just have to buy another cable~